# WAMP server is showing blank pages for everything and the services won't start

Tags: wamp

I have been getting blank pages on all of my projects in WAMP and it's because the WAMP icon in the task tray is orange which means something is not starting correctly.  I have reinstalled WAMP several times.  I have checked the apache and php error logs and there is nothing.  I have seen that other programs use port 80 and can foul up the works with wamp but I checked the resource monitor and there is only one with port 80 while wamp is running.  When I click "Put online" from the wamp manager, it says "Cannot execute menu item" Any ideas?

Edit:  I clicked "Test Port 80" under the apache service menu of the wamp manager and it says this:

```
Your port is actually used by !

Server:  Microsoft-255/10.0
```

Wondering if that has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: Its saying something else is using port 80. However I am not familiar with whatever `Microsoft-255/10.0` might be. Anybody else got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

you should cahnge port number for apache server or close other programms that use this port number like **Skype** or **Microsoft IIS**

go to **C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf** and open **httpd.conf** with a text editor like notepad++ ... find these lines and change the port number from 80 to another number like 70

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:70

Listen [::0]:70

ServerName localhost:70
```

save it and restart all services

Comment: Its best to use a port above 1024 as most below that are reserved for other things.